# VBA: Type Statement vs Class Module

Tags: vba

About VBA Type Statement, I read from internet that one of its drawbacks over class modules is that "*you can't declare new instances of a Type. You must declare all the variables you'll need at design time or you need a dynamic array that is resized with Redim Preserve, an awkward and expensive operation.*"

Could someone explain what does it means? Thank you!

The post I read it is as follows: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `New MyClass` to create a new instance of a class, but there's no equivalent for creating a new "instance" of a Type.

E.g:

```
myCollection.Add New MyClass   'no equivalent for Type
```

I would typically get around that by using a "factory" function.  E.g:

```
Function Person(fName As String, lName As String ) As PersonType
    Dim rv as PersonType    
    rv.FirstName = fName
    rv.LastName = lName
    Person = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Does this actually work? You can't add user defined types to a collection - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24956762/1382318. (Your code gives me the compile error "Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions")

Comment: @neilt17 - no it does not work I guess I'd forgotten that quirk (edited to fix). Thanks for the heads-up. Reminds me why I never find myself using UDT's....