# Runtime Error 91 Object Variable or With block variable not set with a Class

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying my first attempt at getting a recordset from a SQL server and passing the data from the recordset into a class.  This is going to be part of a much bigger project by storing the recordsets into a dictionary that I can call on based on a user entered search criteria, which im sure I will get stuck on too.  I used the [Answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954454/user-defined-types-in-arrays-collections-and-for-each-loops) as a guide to get me started, but since Im just now learning about using the Class Module; I am not sure why I am getting the Run-time error 91(identified in the code below).  I have noticed that nothing seems to pass to the variables that I have designated within the `clsCustInfo`.  Thank you for your assistance.

On quick side note:  The `On Error Resume Next` is for the error that happens when the function tests to see which server the data is stored on.

**Below is what is in my Class Module.**

```
'CustomerInfo.cls
Private CustomerId As String
Private cName As String
Private cAddress1 As String
Private cAddress2 As String
Private cCity As String
Private cState As String
Private cZip As String * 5
Private cDoB As String
Private TableName As String
Private ErrNumber As Long
Public Property Get custID() As String
    custID = CustomerId
End Property
Public Property Let custID(value As String)
    custID = value
End Property
Public Property Get custName() As String
    custName = cName
End Property
Public Property Let custName(value As String)
    custName = value
End Property
Public Property Get custAddress1() As String
    custAddress1 = cAddress1
End Property
Public Property Let custAddress1(value As String)
    custAddress1 = value
End Property
Public Property Get custAddress2() As String
    custAddress2 = cAddress2
End Property
Public Property Let custAddress2(value As String)
    custAddress2 = value
End Property
Public Property Get custCity() As String
    custCity = cCity
End Property
Public Property Let custCity(value As String)
    custCity = value
End Property
Public Property Get custState() As String
    custState = cState
End Property
Public Property Let custState(value As String)
    custState = value
End Property
Public Property Get custZip() As String
    custZip = cZip
End Property
Public Property Let custZip(value As String)
    custZip = value
End Property
Public Property Get custDoB() As String
    custDoB = cDoB
End Property
Public Property Let custDoB(value As String)
    custDoB = value
End Property
Public Property Get tName() As String
    tName = TableName
End Property
Public Property Let tName(value As String)
    tName = value
End Property
Public Property Get eNumber() As Long
    eNumber = ErrNumber
End Property
Public Property Let eNumber(value As Long)
    eNumber = value
End Property
```

**Below is in a Standard Module:**

```
Option Explicit
Const CONNSTR = REDACTED FOR PUBLIC VIEWING

Const ConnectionError As Long = -2147467259
Sub CIFGrab()
    Const bhschlp8 As String = "bhschlp8.jhadat842"
    Const cncttp08 As String = "cncttp08.jhadat842"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'\\\\DATABASE OPERATIONS////

    Dim tDBGrabRecord As clsCustInfo

    tDBGrabRecord.tName = getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(cncttp08)  <---ERROR 91 Happens on this line

    If tDBGrabRecord.eNumber = ConnectionError Then tDBGrabRecord = getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(bhschlp8)


End Sub
Function getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(ByVal tName As String) As clsCustInfo
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim tDBGrabRecord As clsCustInfo

    On Error Resume Next

    conn.Open CONNSTR

    SQL = getCIFDBGrabSQL(tName)

    rs.Open SQL, conn

    tDBGrabRecord.eNumber = Err.Number

    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        If Not tDBGrabRecord.eNumber = ConnectionError Then
            With tDBGrabRecord
                .custID = Trim(rs.Fields("cifNum").value)
                .custName = Trim(rs.Fields("custName").value)
                .custAddress1 = Trim(rs.Fields("stAdd1").value)
                .custAddress2 = Trim(rs.Fields("stAdd2").value)
                .custCity = Trim(rs.Fields("City").value)
                .custState = Trim(rs.Fields("State").value)
                .custZip = Trim(rs.Fields("Zip").value)
                .custDoB = Trim(rs.Fields("DoB").value)
                .tName = tName
            End With
            rs.MoveNext

            With tDBGrabRecord
                Debug.Print "CIF:", .custID, "Name:", .custName, "Street 1:", .custAddress1, _
                            "Street 2:", .custAddress2, "City:", .custCity, "State:", .custState, _
                            "Zip:", .custZip, "DoB:", .custDoB
            End With
        End If
    End If

    rs.Close
    conn.Close

    getCIFDBGrabTestRecord = tDBGrabRecord


End Function
Function getCIFDBGrabSQL(ByVal TableName As String) As String
    Dim SelectClause As String
    Dim FromClause As String
    Dim WhereClause As String
    Dim JoinClause As String

    SelectClause = "SELECT " & _
                   "cfcif# AS cifNum, cfna1 AS custName, " & _
                   "cfna2 AS stAdd1, cfna3 AS stAdd2, " & _
                   "cfcity AS City, cfstat AS State, " & _
                   "left(cfzip,5) AS Zip, " & _
                   "date(digits(decimal(cfdob7 + 0.090000, 7, 0))) AS DoB"
    FromClause = "FROM " & TableName & ".cfmast cfmast"

    WhereClause = "WHERE cfdead = '" & "N" & "'"

    getCIFDBGrabSQL = SelectClause & vbNewLine & FromClause & vbNewLine & WhereClause

End Function
```

Comment: `tDBGrabRecord.tName = getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(cncttp08)`  in the Standard Module,  Sorry @TimWilliams I should have specified it was in the Standard Module under the `Sub CIFGrab`

Comment: `Set getCIFDBGrabTestRecord = tDBGrabRecord` since you're returning an object.  And once you fix that you need to fix `tDBGrabRecord.tName = getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(cncttp08)`

Comment: You need to `New` your customer class.

Comment: Thanks @BrianMStafford I overlooked that while trying to figure everything else out.

Comment: @TimWilliams  I made the following changes `getCIFDBGrabTestRecord = tDBGrabRecord` to `Set getCIFDBGrabTestRecord = tDBGrabRecord` and then `tDBGrabRecord.tName = getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(cncttp08)` to `Set getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(cncttp08) = tDBGrabRecord.tName` and `If tDBGrabRecord.eNumber = ConnectionError Then tDBGrabRecord = getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(bhschlp8)` to `If tDBGrabRecord.eNumber = ConnectionError Then Set getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(bhschlp8) = tDBGrabRecord.tName`, but im still getting the same Object error on the same line as before.

Comment: Now im getting the Runtime 424 error on `Set getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(cncttp08) = tDBGrabRecord.TableName` after it runs through the `Function getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(ByVal tName As String) As clsCustInfo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work - I refactored a little bit.

Compiled but not tested.

```
Option Explicit

Const CONNSTR = "REDACTED FOR PUBLIC VIEWING"

Sub CIFGrab()

    Const bhschlp8 As String = "bhschlp8.jhadat842"
    Const cncttp08 As String = "cncttp08.jhadat842"

    Dim tDBGrabRecord As clsCustInfo

    'passing in all potential table names/sources in array
    Set tDBGrabRecord = getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(Array(bhschlp8, cncttp08))

    If tDBGrabRecord Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Failed to get record", vbExclamation
    Else
        'work with tDBGrabRecord
    End If

End Sub



Function getCIFDBGrabTestRecord(arrNames) As clsCustInfo

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String, nm, okSql As Boolean
    Dim tDBGrabRecord As clsCustInfo

    conn.Open CONNSTR

    'try each provided name: exit loop on successful query
    For Each nm In arrNames

        SQL = getCIFDBGrabSQL(CStr(nm))

        On Error Resume Next
        rs.Open SQL, conn 'try this name
        If Err.Number = 0 Then okSql = True
        On Error GoTo 0 'cancel on error resume next

        If okSql Then
            If Not rs.EOF Then
                Set tDBGrabRecord = New clsCustInfo 'create an instance to populate
                With tDBGrabRecord
                    .custID = Trim(rs.Fields("cifNum").value)
                    .custName = Trim(rs.Fields("custName").value)
                    .custAddress1 = Trim(rs.Fields("stAdd1").value)
                    .custAddress2 = Trim(rs.Fields("stAdd2").value)
                    .custCity = Trim(rs.Fields("City").value)
                    .custState = Trim(rs.Fields("State").value)
                    .custZip = Trim(rs.Fields("Zip").value)
                    .custDoB = Trim(rs.Fields("DoB").value)
                    .tName = CStr(nm)

                    Debug.Print "CIF:", .custID, "Name:", .custName, "Street 1:", .custAddress1, _
                            "Street 2:", .custAddress2, "City:", .custCity, "State:", .custState, _
                            "Zip:", .custZip, "DoB:", .custDoB
                End With
                'rs.MoveNext  'surely this is not needed here?
            End If

            Exit For 'done trying names
        End If
    Next nm

    If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
    If conn.State = adStateOpen Then conn.Close

    Set getCIFDBGrabTestRecord = tDBGrabRecord

End Function

Function getCIFDBGrabSQL(ByVal TableName As String) As String
    Dim SelectClause As String
    Dim FromClause As String
    Dim WhereClause As String
    Dim JoinClause As String

    SelectClause = "SELECT " & _
                   "cfcif# AS cifNum, cfna1 AS custName, " & _
                   "cfna2 AS stAdd1, cfna3 AS stAdd2, " & _
                   "cfcity AS City, cfstat AS State, " & _
                   "left(cfzip,5) AS Zip, " & _
                   "date(digits(decimal(cfdob7 + 0.090000, 7, 0))) AS DoB"
    FromClause = "FROM " & TableName & ".cfmast cfmast"

    WhereClause = "WHERE cfdead = '" & "N" & "'"

    getCIFDBGrabSQL = SelectClause & vbNewLine & FromClause & vbNewLine & WhereClause

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will check it out tomorrow when I'm back in the office and let you know.

Comment: Thanks again Tim.  The only change I had to make was to handle the NULL value of DoB if there was one.  Now its time to figure out how to loop through all that data since there could be over 10000 results returned and store that data it in a Dictionary.